# What VS2017 C++ compiler option can affect matrices multiplication?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The following code multiplies two 4-dimensional identity matrices:

```
const Matrix4 id = Matrix4(
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

auto & a = id;
auto & b = id;

auto m1 = Matrix4(
    a.data[0] * b.data[0] + a.data[4] * b.data[1] + a.data[8] * b.data[2] +
    a.data[12] * b.data[3],

    a.data[0] * b.data[4] + a.data[4] * b.data[5] + a.data[8] * b.data[6] +
    a.data[12] * b.data[7],

    a.data[0] * b.data[8] + a.data[4] * b.data[9] + a.data[8] * b.data[10] +
    a.data[12] * b.data[11],
    a.data[0] * b.data[12] + a.data[4] * b.data[13] + a.data[8] * b.data[14] +
    a.data[12] * b.data[15],
    a.data[1] * b.data[0] + a.data[5] * b.data[1] + a.data[9] * b.data[2] +
    a.data[13] * b.data[3],
    a.data[1] * b.data[4] + a.data[5] * b.data[5] + a.data[9] * b.data[6] +
    a.data[13] * b.data[7],
    a.data[1] * b.data[8] + a.data[5] * b.data[9] + a.data[9] * b.data[10] +
    a.data[13] * b.data[11],
    a.data[1] * b.data[12] + a.data[5] * b.data[13] + a.data[9] * b.data[14] +
    a.data[13] * b.data[15],
    a.data[2] * b.data[0] + a.data[6] * b.data[1] + a.data[10] * b.data[2] +
    a.data[14] * b.data[3],
    a.data[2] * b.data[4] + a.data[6] * b.data[5] + a.data[10] * b.data[6] +
    a.data[14] * b.data[7],
    a.data[2] * b.data[8] + a.data[6] * b.data[9] + a.data[10] * b.data[10] +
    a.data[14] * b.data[11],
    a.data[2] * b.data[12] + a.data[6] * b.data[13] + a.data[10] * b.data[14] +
    a.data[14] * b.data[15],
    a.data[3] * b.data[0] + a.data[7] * b.data[1] + a.data[11] * b.data[2] +
    a.data[15] * b.data[3],
    a.data[3] * b.data[4] + a.data[7] * b.data[5] + a.data[11] * b.data[6] +
    a.data[15] * b.data[7],
    a.data[3] * b.data[8] + a.data[7] * b.data[9] + a.data[11] * b.data[10] +
    a.data[15] * b.data[11],
    a.data[3] * b.data[12] + a.data[7] * b.data[13] + a.data[11] * b.data[14] +
    a.data[15] * b.data[15]);

const int diff_index = 15;

std::cout << "Actual value of element " << diff_index << " is " << m1.data[diff_index] << " expected " << id.data[diff_index] << std::endl;
```

obviously that element 15 of the production is 1.0f, and it is 1.0f in Release configuration, but in **Debug configuration of my project I am getting 0.0f**.

I tried to reproduce this by compiling single .cpp file with command line with the compiler options from my project:

```
cl /GS /TP /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Od /Ob0 /Zc:inline /fp:precise /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /GR /Gd /MDd /FC /EHsc /nologo /diagnostics:classic MatrixTest.cpp
```

but this outputs 1.0f. I can get 0.0f only if I compile MatrixTest.cpp as a part of my project.

Below I provided the definition of the Matrix class that is absolutely trivial:

```
struct Matrix4
{
    float data[16];

    Matrix4(float m00,
        float m01,
        float m02,
        float m03,
        float m10,
        float m11,
        float m12,
        float m13,
        float m20,
        float m21,
        float m22,
        float m23,
        float m30,
        float m31,
        float m32,
        float m33)
    {
        data[0] = m00;
        data[4] = m01;
        data[8] = m02;
        data[12] = m03;
        data[1] = m10;
        data[5] = m11;
        data[9] = m12;
        data[13] = m13;
        data[2] = m20;
        data[6] = m21;
        data[10] = m22;
        data[14] = m23;
        data[3] = m30;
        data[7] = m31;
        data[11] = m32;
        data[15] = m33;
    }
};
```

I believe, it is not a result of a memory corruption, because my project is absolutely trivial and this code already worked for a long time in some real-life app, so I think that something definitely strange is happening.

**UPDATE 1**:

VS2017 15.7.1, compiler version is: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.14.26428.1 for x86

The configuration of the project is Debug 64bit.

The compiler options (with omitted /I and /D) are: /GS /TP /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Od /Ob0 /Fd"ModelTest.dir\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_UNICODE" /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /GR /Gd /MDd /FC /Fa"Debug/" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"ModelTest.dir\Debug\" /Fp"ModelTest.dir\Debug\ModelTest.pch" /diagnostics:classic

The project (.sln and .vcxproj) is generated by cmake-3.11.2-win64-x64.

Comment: If the code you've supplied can't produce the problem, then the problem must be with code you haven't supplied. It seems like you have undefined behavior elsewhere and that all of this code is irrelevant to identifying the actual problem.

Comment: My VS2017 compiler version is Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.14.26428.1 for x86

Comment: Still... this is just basic math. Nothing special, even the qualification *matrix multiplication* is to strong. An optimizer could do some tricks but if you are debugging that's unlikely. Maybe there is something else in your cpp file which is causing this behavior. Btw, how are you compiling without it in the release build?

Comment: In my project I just call testMatrix() from main() and return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a compiler bug in VS 15.7.2 (19.14) x64.

There's not enough floating point registers to perform all the calculations. 
Old version (v140) offloads xmm14 onto the stack. But vc141 overflows onto xmm0, which happens to contain the value for the 16th argument.

Compare [vc140 vs. vc141](http://www.mergely.com/7sfgbIqu/) assembly. (for [**source.cpp**](https://pastebin.com/hXsUJtvF)):

vc140:

```
  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rdx+rax]  
  mulss       xmm1,dword ptr [r8+rcx]  
  addss       xmm0,xmm1  
. . .
  movss       dword ptr [rsp+1A8h],xmm14  < save xmm14
. . .
  movss       xmm15,dword ptr [rdx+rax]  
  mulss       xmm15,dword ptr [r8+rcx]  
  addss       xmm14,xmm15
  movss       dword ptr [rsp+80h],xmm0  < push xmm0
```

vc141:

```
  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rdx+rax]  
  mulss       xmm1,dword ptr [r8+rcx]  
  addss       xmm0,xmm1  
. . .
. . .
  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [rdx+rax]  < overwrites xmm0  
  mulss       xmm0,dword ptr [r8+rcx]  
  addss       xmm15,xmm0  
  movss       dword ptr [rsp+80h],xmm0  < push xmm0
```

As a workaround, you can calculate the last argument separately and store in a temporary.

Comment: Hmm... if this is correct my *this is just basic math* wasn't really appropriate...

Comment: If this is true, this might be yet another side-effect bug of the 32-registers support for AVX512. They added that in 15.7 and with it came a multitude of problems from incorrect compilation to ICEs.